# Avoid temporaries in std::map/std::unordered_map lookup with std::string key

Tags: c++, stl

Consider the following code:

```
std::map<std::string, int> m1;
auto i = m1.find("foo");

const char* key = ...
auto j = m1.find(key);
```

This will create a temporary std::string object for every map lookup. What are the canonical ways to avoid it?

Comment: If you could change the definition of the map, you could use a custom comparator that allows `char const*` directly

Comment: Where would you even get a `const char*`?

Comment: @Pablo: But then.. someone will have to manage a memory where those keys are pointing.. unless they are all in data segment...

Comment: @Pablo yes and you will have to manage raw strings yourself on the heap. This is where I am right now. I want to get rid of as much custom code as possible without sacrificing performance.

Comment: I didn't mean to change the definition of the map to hold `char const*`, I meant to change the comparator to allow storing `std::string` and comparing with `char const*` without creating a temporary `std::string`

Comment: Nevermind.. like @VladLazarenko said below, find takes a `const key&` anyway so the custom comparator won't even see the original `char const*` argument.

Comment: C++14 introduces "transparent comparators" to allow for heterogeneous comparison operations, e.g. between `std::string` and a char pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use pointers; instead, pass strings directly. Then you can take advantage of references:

```
void do_something(std::string const & key)
{
    auto it = m.find(key);
    // ....
}
```

C++ typically becomes "more correct" the more you use its idioms and don't try to write C with it.

Comment: ... unless you really need to write C. But then.. why do you need C++ at all? :-D

Comment: Although this doesn't address the `m1.find("foo")` creating a temporary object issue (even if, ultimately, this temporary can't be bypassed).

Comment: I can't avoid using pointers. I do lookup for a value that comes from external source as a C string. This still means I have to construct a string for every lookup.

Comment: @AndréCaron: Why would you ever need to find a string literal? In that case, just make a global constant `std::string const foo_string("foo")` and use that...

Comment: @AlexB: Clean interfaces. Make the string once at the external library boundary, and then reuse that string. You don't have a pure C++ question, so this is a bit misleading.

Comment: @KerrekSB there is a new string is every time. Consider it like a big stream of them. The lookup is done only once, when I pull a new string from this "stream".

Comment: @KerrekSB: doesn't matter why someone would want to do that (although less typing comes to mind).  Perhaps your answer should take the form "you can't bypass the temporary, but by doing ... you can really alleviate the cost of creating a `std::string` instance".  This of course goes out the window after Alex's last comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the temporary by giving the `std::map` a custom comparator class, that can compare `char *`s. (The default will use the pointer's address, which isn't what you want. You need to compare on the string's value.)

Thus, something like:

```
class StrCmp
{
public:
  bool operator () (const char *a, const char *b)
  {
    return strcmp(a, b) < 0;
  }
};

// Later:
std::map<const char *, int, StrCmp> m;
```

Then, use like a normal map, but pass char *'s. Keep in mind that anything you store in the map **must remain alive for the duration of the map**. That means you need char literals, or you have to keep the data pointed to by the pointer alive on your own. For these reasons, I'd go with a `std::map<std::string>` and eat the temporary until profiling showed that the above was really needed.

Comment: To the downvoter: mind explaining your downvote?

Comment: Your words sound like the custom comparator works with `std::map<std::string,int,StrCmp>` but your example doesn't. What did you intend to suggest?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to avoid a temporary `std::string` instance that copies character data.  Note that this cost is very low and does not incur dynamic memory allocation if your standard library implementation uses short string optimizations.

However, if you need to proxy C-style strings on a frequent basis, you can still come up with custom solutions that will by-pass this allocation.  This can pay off if you have to do this *really* often and your strings are lengthy enough not to benefit from short string optimizations.

If you only need a *very* small subset of string functionality (e.g. only assignment and copies), then you can write a small special-purpose string class that stores a `const char *` pointer and a function to release the memory.

```
 class cheap_string
 {
 public:
     typedef void(*Free)(const char*);
 private:
     const char * myData;
     std::size_t mySize;
     Free myFree;
 public:
     // direct member assignments, use with care.
     cheap_string ( const char * data, std::size_t size, Free free );

     // releases using custom deleter (a no-op for proxies).
     ~cheap_string ();

     // create real copies (safety first).
     cheap_string ( const cheap_string& ); 
     cheap_string& operator= ( const cheap_string& ); 
     cheap_string ( const char * data );
     cheap_string ( const char * data, std::size_t size )
         : myData(new char[size+1]), mySize(size), myFree(&destroy)
     {
         strcpy(myData, data);
         myData[mySize] = '\0';
     }

     const char * data () const;
     const std::size_t size () const;

     // whatever string functionality you need.
     bool operator< ( const cheap_string& ) const;
     bool operator== ( const cheap_string& ) const;

     // create proxies for existing character buffers.
     static const cheap_string proxy ( const char * data )
     {
          return cheap_string(data, strlen(data), &abandon);
     }

     static const cheap_string proxy ( const char * data, std::size_t size )
     {
          return cheap_string(data, size, &abandon);
     }

 private:
     // deleter for proxies (no-op)
     static void abandon ( const char * data )
     {
         // no-op, this is used for proxies, which don't own the data!
     }

     // deleter for copies (delete[]).
     static void destroy ( const char * data )
     {
         delete [] data;
     }
 };
```

Then, you can use this class as:

```
 std::map<cheap_string, int> m1;
 auto i = m1.find(cheap_string::proxy("foo"));
```

The temporary `cheap_string` instance does not create a copy of the character buffer like `std::string` does, yet it preserves safe copy semantics for storing instances of `cheap_string` in standard containers.

**notes**: if your implementation does not use return value optimization, you'll want to find an alternate syntax for the `proxy` method, such as a constructor with a special overload (taking a custom `proxy_t` type à la `std::nothrow` for placement new).

Comment: …but by your definition of `cheap_string`, would it not try to (incorrectly) free `"foo"` once the temporary was deleted?

Comment: No, because the `proxy()` method uses the custom deleter `abandon()` which is a no-op that never calls delete.  Let me elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Well, map's `find` actually accepts a constant reference to the key, so you cannot avoid creating it at one point or another.

For the first part of the code you can have a constant static std::string with value "foo" to lookup. That way you won't create copies.

If you want to go Spartan's way, you can always create your own type that can be used like a string, but also can hold pointer to string literals.

But in any event, overhead associated with map lookups is so huge so this doesn't really make sense. If I were you I'd first replace map/unordered_map with google's dense hash. Then I would run Intel's VTune (amplifier these days) and see where the time is going and optimize those places. I doubt strings as keys will show up at a bottleneck top ten list.

Comment: I must be missing something, but who's Spartan?

Comment: @Cameron: I believe he's the author of the Aegean C compiler. Very frugal and industrious.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [StringRef](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1StringRef.html) class from llvm.

They can be constructed very cheap from c-strings, string literals or std::string.  If you made a map of those, instead of std::string, the construction would be very fast.

It's a very fragile system though.  You need to be sure that whatever the source of the strings you insert stays alive and unmodified for the lifetime of the map.